# PHP script to write a list of folder names inside a directory into .html file

Tags: php

I would like to create a php script which reads the folders located in a specific directory and writes the names in a .html file, the structure of the HTML should be:

```
<ul class="galleries">
<li><a href=".../control/includes/gallery-select.php?g=folder-xx">Gallery 1</a></li>
<li><a href=".../control/includes/gallery-select.php?g=folder-xx">Gallery 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

where folder-xx are the names of the folders in control\data\img\gallery\

I'm not a big expert of php so i'll be grateful for any hint.. and sorry for the english.

Thanks

Comment: you probably want to show the list on page request, rather than writing it to a file, my hint - start with [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: You'll find it easier to get help if you include in your question the code you have so far, and more details about exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: i need an .html file because i would consider it a block and just use ?php include

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```php
echo "<ul>";
$folder_name = ".";
$d = opendir($folder_name);
while ($f = readdir($d)) {
    if (is_dir($folder_name."/".$f))
        echo "<li><a href='your_script.php?dir=$f'>$f</a></li>";
}
closedir($d);
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: glob is better, well its name is anyway

Comment: Maybe, but opendir is classic way :)

Comment: thanks for the help but i get only dots instead of folder names

Comment: thanks, it works but on the top of the list there are also an element with just one dot and another with two dots.. how can i remove them?

Comment: Thanks for the help i fixed with
    if( $filename != ".." && $filename != "." && is_dir($dir.$filename) )